# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when using distribution profile

Tags: ios, iphone

When use develop profile everything is ok.app can run in simulator and real phone.But when use distribution profile,it crashes in lauching page.And crashes only happened in distribution profile.So it sounds so strange.
What's more,I am using enterprise profile.
Here is the crash log.

```
Incident Identifier: 35311121-D805-45AC-86D4-0F2D23FC6A0F
CrashReporter Key:   d5d38df3c00b48e5d091b65c20d5ab3c373c35fd
Hardware Model:      iPhone6,2
Process:             GSD_ZHIFUBAO [271]
Path:                /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/A36A0DCC-178E-4251-B611-F8C163EB705F/GSD_ZHIFUBAO.app/GSD_ZHIFUBAO
Identifier:          com.nice.one
Version:             6 (2.0)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2016-01-19 16:05:32.32 +0800
Launch Time:         2016-01-19 16:05:30.30 +0800
OS Version:          iOS 9.2 (13C75)
Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGABRT)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000010
Triggered by Thread:  0

Filtered syslog:
None found

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x184161900 __exceptionPreprocess + 124
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x1837cff80 objc_exception_throw + 56
2   CoreFoundation                  0x184161848 +[NSException raise:format:] + 120
3   GSD_ZHIFUBAO                    0x1004677d4 UmengSignalHandler + 144
4   libsystem_platform.dylib        0x183dc593c _sigtramp + 52
5   Foundation                      0x184b0af40 ____addOperations_block_invoke + 328
6   Foundation                      0x184b08c84 __addOperations + 292
7   GSD_ZHIFUBAO                    0x1000a5738 -[NetworkClient postPath:baseUrl:parameters:attachHeaders:isDelete:completion:failure:] (NetworkClient.m:287)
8   GSD_ZHIFUBAO                    0x100095b78 -[Netclient postUserinfo:failureBlock:] (Netclient.m:68)
9   GSD_ZHIFUBAO                    0x1000427e0 -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] (AppDelegate.m:172)
10  UIKit                           0x188ec9704 -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 400
11  UIKit                           0x1890f8130 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 2904
12  UIKit                           0x1890fc4b8 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1672
13  UIKit                           0x1890f95c0 -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 168
14  FrontBoardServices              0x185717790 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 184
15  FrontBoardServices              0x185717b10 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 56
16  CoreFoundation                  0x184118efc __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
17  CoreFoundation                  0x184118990 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 540
18  CoreFoundation                  0x184116690 __CFRunLoopRun + 724
19  CoreFoundation                  0x184045680 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384
20  UIKit                           0x188ec2580 -[UIApplication _run] + 460
21  UIKit                           0x188ebcd90 UIApplicationMain + 204
22  GSD_ZHIFUBAO                    0x100091104 main (main.m:14)
23  libdyld.dylib                   0x183be68b8 start + 4


Global Trace Buffer (reverse chronological seconds):
6148914688.454477 CFNetwork                     0x000000018473984c TCP Conn 0x154739670 SSL Handshake DONE
6148914688.544633 CFNetwork                     0x000000018473984c TCP Conn 0x154747a20 SSL Handshake DONE
6148914689.195506 CFNetwork                     0x000000018473975c TCP Conn 0x154747a20 starting SSL negotiation
6148914689.195804 CFNetwork                     0x00000001847db104 TCP Conn 0x154747a20 complete. fd: 16, err: 0
6148914689.196920 CFNetwork                     0x00000001847dc630 TCP Conn 0x154747a20 event 1. err: 0
6148914689.222770 CFNetwork                     0x000000018473975c TCP Conn 0x154739670 starting SSL negotiation
6148914689.223070 CFNetwork                     0x00000001847db104 TCP Conn 0x154739670 complete. fd: 15, err: 0
6148914689.224137 CFNetwork                     0x00000001847dc630 TCP Conn 0x154739670 event 1. err: 0
6148914689.516014 CFNetwork                     0x00000001847dc708 TCP Conn 0x154747a20 started
6148914689.604255 CFNetwork                     0x00000001847dc708 TCP Conn 0x154739670 started
6148914689.721041 CFNetwork                     0x00000001847db104 TCP Conn 0x1545b1ad0 complete. fd: 6, err: 0
6148914689.721764 CFNetwork                     0x00000001847dc630 TCP Conn 0x1545b1ad0 event 1. err: 0
6148914689.791580 CFNetwork                     0x00000001847dc708 TCP Conn 0x1545b1ad0 started
6148914689.795240 CFNetwork                     0x00000001848318bc Creating default cookie storage with default identifier
6148914689.795240 CFNetwork                     0x0000000184831888 Faulting in CFHTTPCookieStorage singleton
6148914689.795291 CFNetwork                     0x0000000184883558 Faulting in NSHTTPCookieStorage singleton



Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000183d04140 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183dccef8 pthread_kill + 112
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000183c75dac abort + 140
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001837a93f4 __cxa_bad_cast + 0
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001837c2f60 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 44
5   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001837c285c __cxxabiv1::exception_cleanup_func(_Unwind_Reason_Code, _Unwind_Exception*) + 0
6   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001837d0094 _objc_exception_destructor(void*) + 0
7   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000184161848 -[NSException initWithCoder:] + 0
8   GSD_ZHIFUBAO                    0x00000001004677d4 UmengSignalHandler + 144
9   libsystem_platform.dylib        0x0000000183dc593c _sigtramp + 52
10  Foundation                      0x0000000184b0af40 ____addOperations_block_invoke + 328
11  Foundation                      0x0000000184b08c84 __addOperations + 292
12  GSD_ZHIFUBAO                    0x00000001000a5738 -[NetworkClient postPath:baseUrl:parameters:attachHeaders:isDelete:completion:failure:] (NetworkClient.m:288)
13  GSD_ZHIFUBAO                    0x0000000100095b78 -[Netclient postUserinfo:failureBlock:] (Netclient.m:121)
14  GSD_ZHIFUBAO                    0x00000001000427e0 -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] (AppDelegate.m:172)
15  UIKit                           0x0000000188ec9704 -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 400
16  UIKit                           0x00000001890f8130 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 2904
17  UIKit                           0x00000001890fc4b8 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1672
18  UIKit                           0x00000001890f95c0 -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 168
19  FrontBoardServices              0x0000000185717790 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 184
20  FrontBoardServices              0x0000000185717b10 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 56
21  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000184118efc __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
```

Answer (score 0):

I think its trying to access deallocated memory.Exception subtype denotes it.

```
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000010
```

Just enable zombies object to track exact line of code which creates crash.

You can enable zombies by Go To **Edit Scheme**  of project settings.
Please check below images to enable zombies.

[image]

[image]

Comment: thank you,but i have already enable Zombie Objects.The problem is that nothing went wrong in debug mode